# for loop run over factor levels to plot several plots not working

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2

I am trying to run a for loop over a factor level (treatment in this case) to plot graphs for each of the levels using a function. My goal is to obtain several graphs on my wd(), one for each treatment level.
**Problem**: The outcome is always one single messed up barplot with all the variables and errorbars included.

dataset looks something like this:

```
    set.seed(108) test <- data.frame(
        n = 1:12,
        treatment = factor(paste("trt", 1:2)),
        rep= factor(paste("rep", 1:2)),
        type = sample(LETTERS, 3),
        mean= sample(1:100, 12),
        sd= sample(1:50, 12),
        var3 = sample(1:100, 12),
        var4 = sample(1:100, 12))
```

I believe that I'm missing something on my for loop code:

df$treatment<- as.factor(df$treatment)
treatment_levels<- unique(levels(df$treatment))

```
for(i in 1:length(treatment_levels)){

  df <- df[treatment_levels[i],]
  x <- df$type
  avg <- df$mean
  sd <-  df$sd
  grp<- df$rep
  title<- treatment_levels[i]
  xtitle<- "type"
  ytitle<- " "
  fig_name <- paste(title,"_bp")
  
   bpfunction(df, x, avg, sd, grp, title, xtitle, ytitle, fig_name)
}
```

my function to plot a barplot is:

```
bpfunction(df, x, avg, sd, grp, title, xtitle, ytitle, fig_name)
{
bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = avg, fill = grp)) +
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = grp), size = 1) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=avg-sd , ymax=avg +sd))+
        labs(x = x, y = avg, title = title)
ggsave(paste(fig_name, "png", sep = "."), plot = bp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues with your implementation:

- Currently, your row indexing is not logical but factor value:

  ```r
  df <- df[treatment_levels[i],]
  ```

  Therefore, adjust to proper filtering by column:

  ```r
  sub_df <- df[df$treatment == treatment_levels[i],]
  ```

  Better yet, avoid bookkeeping of unique treatment  factor levels and use `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`)  or `split` + `lapply`.
- Reassigning `df` in a for loop. After first iteration, `df` can no longer be subsetted for other treatment values. Therefore, use a different object name. (Actually, avoid `df` altogether for more substantive name).
- Using a numeric vector of many values as labels per your `labs` argument.
- Avoid passing vectors pointing to data frame columns into `aes`. Instead, pass string variables to be dynamically rendered with [**`.data[[]]`**](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html#using-aes-and-vars-in-a-package-function) or double curly brace `{{}}` (ggplot2 v3.0.0+):

  ```r
  bpfunction(treatment_df, x, avg, sd, grp, title, xtitle, ytitle, fig_name)
  {
    bp <- ggplot(treatment_df, aes(x = .data[[x]], y = .data[[avg]], fill = .data[[grp]])) +
            geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = .data[[grp]]), size = 1) + 
            geom_errorbar(aes(ymin={{avg}}-{{sd}}, ymax={{avg}}+{{sd}})) +
            labs(x = x, y = avg, title = title)

    ggsave(fig_name, plot = bp)

    return(bp)
  }

  # REFACTOR USING by
  treatment_plots <- by(df, df$treatment, function(sub_df) 
      bpfunction(
          sub_df, 
          x = "type", 
          avg = "mean", 
          sd = "sd", 
          grp = "rep", 
          title sub_df$treatment[1], 
          xtitle = "type", 
          ytitle = " ", 
          fig_name = paste0(sub_df$treatment[1], "_bp.png")
      )
  )

  # REFACTOR USING split + lapply
  treatment_plots <- split(df, df$treatment) |> lapply(
      function(sub_df) bp_function(...same as above...)
  )
  ```

Comment: _Please excuse any typos as I answered this on mobile._